# Excel - How can I search a row of cells in Sheet1 for a value and return the column header value in Sheet2?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I make a schedule for about eight people for myself to keep track of where everyone is working, but I want to make something semi-automated to strip out each individual person's schedule into a separate section. So Sheet 1 is my master with Column1 as the Date, Column2 is Position1, Column3 is Position2, and on and on with the person's name in the cell. So Row10: 4/24/19, Column4: Director, Cell10;4: Chris. On 4/24/19, the Director is Chris.

In Sheet 2, I want to set it up as Column1: Name, Column2: Date, Column3: Position. I'm fine with manually changing Columns 1 and 2 as needed, but if I can save time with Column 3 by making it automatically look through the master sheet, that would be amazing.

Comment: The first part is a bit confusing, and a sample image would help a lot. If you only want to Sheet2, column 3 ("C") to show the position based on the name, You could use INDEX and MATCH. Something like `=INDEX(Sheet1!B2:B10,MATCH(A2,D2:D10,0))` Or however your data sis structured.

Comment: @Chris, edit your post and upload Sample data and Screen Shot along with expected Output!!